# Testing a boolean being returned by inner method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, powermockito

I need to test if the boolean value returned by the checkIt function when I call Myfunction with 'hello', it should return true.

```
public class Myclass 
{
    public void Myfunction(x)
       {

        if(x!= null) 
        {
        boolean containsHello;
        containsHello = checkIt(x) 
        }

        Rest of the statements for Myfunction  ------- 
        goes here -------
    }

     @VisibleForTesting
     boolean checkIt(String x)
     {
      return x.contains('hello');
     }
```

I want to unit test if the checkIt function returns true when I pass 'hello' to Myfunction in Mockito. I tried the below code but it does not seem to work

```
String loc = Mockito.spy('hello');
        Mockito.verify(Myclass).checkIt(x);
        Assert.assertEquals(true, checkIt(loc));
```

Comment: You don't need Mockito here. Your code is just checking if a certain String appears in the passed in value. You would need Mockito if you were trying to verify some kind of interaction with the variable.

Comment: Could you show an example in detail on the implementation?

Answer (score 1):

As cwa mentioned, you don't need to create a spy - just use a string directly. Additionally, in Java you'll need to use double quotes for strings in Java. This will look like:

```java
Assert.assertEquals(true, checkIt("some string"));
```